# Parsing json list from Gatling response body

Tags: json, scala, gatling, stress-testing

The tested site responds with following json:

```
{
  results: [ 
    foo1,
    foo2,
    ...
  ]
}
```

I would like to extract only the size of list under "results" key.

I know I can use jsonPath to extract json keys, but it returns String and I don't know how to read it as List:

```
    exec(http(requestName)
      .get("/result/${" + responseId + "}")
      .check(status is 200)
      .check(jsonPath("results").saveAs(responseId))
    )
```

Is there a way of further parsing the json to get list entity?

Comment: You should have access to result size when parsing json, for sure. Is this not enough?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this particular use-case. There is no need for additional json parsing, instead you should write:

```
    exec(http(requestName)
      .get("/result/${" + responseId + "}")
      .check(status is 200)
      .check(jsonPath("$").ofType[Seq[Any]].saveAs(responseBodyId)))
    )
```

```
jsonPath("path").ofType[Seq[Any]]
```

matches Seq[Any], so it can either to be used to getting seq size or further parsing.